# String interpolation of a string stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, string, interpolation

I am trying to prepare some SQL query for Amazon Athena with dynamic 'WHERE' conditions in JavaScript. The query was saved on one variable in another file. How to add custom WHERE condition to it?

Pseudocode that I am trying to achieve,

file1.js

```
module.exports.queryFromFile1 = 'SELECT * Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = ?';
```

file2.js

```
const {queryFromFile1} = require('./file1.js');

const newQuery = queryFromFile1,['Jane']; 
console.log(newQuery); // 'SELECT * Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Jane'
```

Can anyone suggest to me a proper method to do it. my current solution is posted below.

file1.js

```
module.exports.queryFromFile1 = 'SELECT * Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = {stringToReplace}';
```

file2.js

```
const {queryFromFile1} = require('./file1.js');

const newQuery = queryFromFile1.replace("{stringToReplace}", "'Jane"); 
console.log(newQuery); // 'SELECT * Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Jane'
```

Comment: Please just use prepared statements. There is no need to open yourself to [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/) by doing this by hand

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the comment. could you explain a bit more on prepared statements. the query that i am preparing is not for MYSQL/MSSQL it is for amazon Athena.

Comment: [`db.execute(queryFromFile1, ['Jane'])`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-prepared-statements)

Comment: hi, @LawrenceCherone, I' am trying to execute this query to  [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc), so the mentioned method does not works for me.

Comment: I guess you meant `SELECT * FROM Contact` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a little helper function that let's you use straight es6 string interpolation in a round about way:

```
const template= (template, ctx) => {
   const script = new vm.Script('`' + template + '`')
   return script.runInNewContext(ctx)
}

const results = template('hello ${foo}', {foo:'jane'})
```

But, if you just need to do do a simple interpolation, why not just export the sql as a function?

```
const queryFromFile1 = str => (`SELECT * Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = ${str}`)

const query = queryFromFile1('Jane')
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should not handle SQL statements with raw strings.

However, for a non-security critical parts of your code (for example, taking in a date format string from component props), this is how I prefer to do this:

```js
const stringProducer = (insert) => `This was inserted: ${insert}`;
```

Then use like this:

```js
const string = stringProducer("foo");
```